# TSQL computated column: prepend with zero until limit

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have a computed column in my table which prepends zeros to an `int` from another column. Using the following:

```
client_id AS RIGHT('00000' + CAST(id AS nvarchar(5)) , 5) PERSISTED NOT NULL
```

Basically, it converts the `id` to a `NVARCHAR(5)`, and prepends it with `00000` and then grabs the five right-most characters. This works great, however if my id number is greater than 99999 (thus 6 digits) it will trim off the first digit. This is expected but unwanted.

How would I create a computed column that grabs a number from another column (`id`) then forces the following format `00000` unless the number is greater than 99999?

Example:

```
 00001  
 00002  
 00003  
 ..   
 00010  
 00100  
 01000  
 99999   
 ..   
100000  
100001
```

Thank you, and I apologize for the confusing title.

Comment: Why is this a persisted computed computed column and why is it `nvarchar`? It contains no non ASCII characters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is a variable length because it could be 5,6,7.. characters long. And I am using `nvarchar` because our database "administrator" is in fear of the future; specifically the almost non-existing potential need to use double-byte characters (not sure why for numbers).

Comment: But why a persisted computed column? For a 7 digit integer `id` that is stored in 4 bytes you will waste another 16 bytes (2 bytes per unicode char + 2 bytes variable column overhead) storing a persisted `nvarchar` copy of it.

Comment: Now that you are asking, I am not sure why this has been decided.. maybe performance? But the application is small scale. I will look into this, thank you for your additional feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to only pre-pend the zeros if the number is less than 10000:

```
client_id AS (
    case when [id] < 100000
    then right('00000'+convert([nvarchar](20), [id]), 5) 
    else convert([nvarchar](20), [id]) end) PERSISTED NOT NULL
```

I use `nvarchar(20)` above, but you should use whatever length is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Then use a `CASE`:

```
SELECT client_id = CASE 
                 WHEN id > 99999 THEN id 
                 ELSE RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, id), 5) 
               END 
FROM   dbo.table1
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09798/5/0)

Note that ...
`char` and `nchar` are fixed-length which will reserve storage space for number of characters you specify even if you don't use up all that space.
but
`varchar` and `nvarchar` are **variable-length** which will only use up spaces for the characters you store. It **will not reserve storage like char or nchar**.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @p TABLE (id INT)

INSERT INTO @p
select 1 UNION
SELECT 100 union
SELECT 100000 UNION
SELECT 1000000

SELECT ISNULL( REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(p.id)), '') + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(ISNULL(p.id, 0) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))))
FROM @p p
```

Result

```
(4 row(s) affected)

00001
00100
100000
1000000
```